# How to save to the next available row instead of replacing it

Tags: vba, excel

I had tried to use VBA to help grab values from a Excel form into a another workbook (Which is blank inside for now) here is the VBA code I'm using:

```
Sub RunMe()
    Dim lRow, lCol As Integer

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For Each cell In Range(Cells(1, "B"), Cells(1, lCol))
        Union(Range("A1:A" & lRow), Range(Cells(1, cell.Column), Cells(lRow, cell.Column))).Copy
        Workbooks.Add
        Range("A1").PasteSpecial
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
          "C:\Users\john\Desktop\Testforvba" & cell.Value & ".xls"
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Next cell

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

But the thing is that when I run this code after inputting a sample value on the form and manually run the macro, it works as it creates a new file and store the sample data I had type on the Form workbook.
But once I tried running the macro again, I realised that it recreates the file AGAIN which means it replace all the previous data. VBA is so dang hard lol. Anyone please give a hand thanks.

P.S The macro I stored in my personal Workbook

Comment: Well you are creating new file every time you run the code, why not look for the file first then create one if it does not exist

Comment: Side notes: (1) You **must** specify the type of **every** variable. Declaring `Dim lRow, lCol As Integer` only `lCol` is `Interger` and `IRow` remains `Variant`. Also you must use `Long` for row counting variables (or never use Integer at all unless communicating with old 16bit APIs): `Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long`. (2) [Never assume the Worksheet](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9218/never-assume-the-worksheet) always fully qualify your cells/ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RunMe()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long

    Dim wb As Workbook, wbNew as Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsNew as Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    lRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lCol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Dim cell As Variant
    For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, "B"), ws.Cells(1, lCol))
        Union(ws.Range("A1:A" & lRow), ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, cell.Column), ws.Cells(lRow, cell.Column))).Copy
        Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
        Set wsNew = wbNew.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Dim yourdesktopaddress As String
        yourdesktopaddress = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop") & "\Testforvba"
        wsNew.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    If Not Dir(yourdesktopaddress & "\" & cell.Value & ".xls", vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
       'MsgBox "exists"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Else
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        yourdesktopaddress & "\" & cell.Value & ".xls"
    End If

    wbNew.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True        
    Next cell

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

The main issue was, whenever macro runs, Excel was creating the files from zero and this was causing Excel to recreate each file again. I have added that  `If Not Dir(yourdesktopaddress & "\Testforvba" & cell.Value & ".xls", vbDirectory) = vbNullString` part of my code to check whether did this file already created or not, if not it's creating the file now. If you delete the "**'**" from the beginning of `'MsgBox "exists"` it will always tell you that this file is already exist.

***Also*** In the case of variables are not defined well, excel might start to overwrite itself and it may replace the previous data. (Especially `Range("A1).PasteSpecial` and `Activeworkbook.close` kind of critical points are most important ones) So I also edited whole code,defined all variables, defined the user's desktop address to ensure code works on every user.

Comment: What is the different between your code and the OP's code?

Comment: yea.. i tried the code but it still does the same to find the current file and replacing the whole file..

Comment: @0m3r I added the explanation as well, this new IF statements made the main difference now, like your suggestion above.

Comment: @Mertinc you still should fix your code here: **Every** `Range` and `Cell` should reference to a worksheet like `ws.Range` anything else is still bad practice.

Comment: one more question if you dont mind, (yourdesktopaddress & "\Testforvba" & cell.Value & ".xls") does this refer to desktop\Testforvba <- which is my folder called 'Testforvba' and i dont quite understand the cell.value.. my database file is named as database.xlsx

Comment: @user7809596 I added  `& "\Testforvba"` to the end of this code to define your folder as Testforvba. `yourdesktopaddress = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop") & "\Testforvba"`
Now it will save it to Testforvba folder.

Comment: @Peh there was thousands of them & I was missing some of them each time lol. Now hopefully everything is fine?

Comment: But how do i let it focus on that specific excel file called 'Database'?

Comment: You have specified `cell.Value` as your new workbook name in your question. And I don't understand where do you want to use that `Database` name?

Comment: that cell.Value as *you* defined in your question, is either B1 or C1 or D1 or E1.... it depends on which stage your code is in and then *you* again defined it to be the workbook name. @user7809596

Comment: ah my bad, it was my friend that told me to input that. but i dont see the cell.value to be working tho.. i will try and direct it to my 'Database' file. Thanks!

Comment: So, as long as your question is solved please don't forget to approve this answer as an answer. You are welcome. @user7809596